# Determine if ASP.Net Core webapp is running on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

At my company developer machines are behind a proxy. I have a scenario where I need to provide my credentials for it and I am accomplishing it via the HttpClient.DefaultProxy. However, on Staging and Production servers there is no proxy. What I would like to do is determine if the application is running against local host and only set the default proxy in that scenario. In the past I've looked at the HttpRequest to determine that information. For this I need to apply the logic in the Startup file.

So far the only solution I've come up with that is somewhat clean is checking for an attached debugger. That isn't ideal though since we also run these applications locally without the debugger attached. 
Another option would be to use a middleware then check the url for "localhost" but that seems excessive.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (/*Some clean way to determine IsLocal*/)
   {
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
   }
}
```

**To clarify to prevent question removal - I would like to determine if localhost before an httprequest exists.**

---

**Update** I've chosen to go with using lauchSetting.json which also isn't perfect but fits the best for my case. I'll go a head and outline all the options and their pros/cons for any future dev in the same position.

**Option 1:** Add Local Environment 
**Problems:** If you have Environment specific configs already you'll spend time copy pasting configuration if you want to target "Staging" from your "Local" config file. 
**Code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (HostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Local"))
   {
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
   }
}
```

**Option 2:** Create a Middleware to check for localhost in request url
**Problems:** Depending on how its implemented it might be run too often. It also doesn't work in the event you're local version isn't using localhost in the url.

**Option 3:** Use launchSettings.json to house an environmentVariable 
**Problems:** Depending on your IDE this may not work. It assumes you commit your launchSettings.json file. 
**Code**

```
{
   "profiles": {
      "IIS Express": {
         "commandName": "IISExpress",
         "launchBrowser": true,
         "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            "IsLocal": "True"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IsLocal") == "True")
   {
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
   }
}
```

**Option 3.5:** Use actual environment variable 
**Problems:** Requires additional developer setup beyond checking out code and running

**Option 4:** Use Machine Names to determine if developer or server 
**Problems:** Assumes all developer machines are using some kind of standard.  
**Code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (Environment.MachineName.StartsWith("DEV", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
   }
}
```

**Option 5:** Check for an attached debugger 
**Problems:** Debugger isn't always attached when you're running locally  
**Code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   if (Debugger.IsAttached)
   {
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
   }
}
```

**Option 6:** Use compile time debug check 
**Problems:** Might not want to compile in debug in every scenario 
**Code**

```
#if(DEBUG)
       //Need to provide proxy credentials for local development only
       var proxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Username"], Configuration["ProxyCredentials:Password"]);
       HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.company.com:80", false, null, proxyCredentials);
#endif
```

Comment: Are we talking ASP.NET Core?

Comment: If it's just for development, how about using either `#if DEBUG` or `if (hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())`?

Comment: @CodeStranger Yes .net core

Comment: If you ping the server name you will get back the IP address which may help.  Then compare against a ping with localhost.  The problem may be local host returns 127.0.0.1 sometimes depending on the host file of the machine.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Unfortunately we actually already have a true development environment that isn't local. We also use environment configuration on local machine to connect to the correct databases/apis etc so using the hosting environment wouldn't work well. if DEBUG is my fallback but isn't ideal since we aren't always running locally in debug

Comment: @WilliamGates you can define your own configurations , could make one for each scenario

Comment: @TheBatman do you mean environment configs? Adding additional environment configs isn't a great option for our stack - we are pretty locked into environment configurations existing due integration with outside resources. But if you're referring to something else could you elaborate?

Comment: you can create do it based on `#If` but it might just be easier to add a configuration value for whether it's a proxy, and just check that e.g(`if(Config["ProxySettings:IsProxy"]`))

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variant of your **Option 4** with a small one-line whitelisting

```
if("|PC1|PC2|PC3|".Contains("|" + Environment.MachineName + "|"))
{
    // proxy code here
}
```

... and then be done with it.

I think that would be a good pragmatic solution.

Remember: perfect is the enemy of good.

I don't know the context but in case maybe you are the primary developer working on this corner of the codebase this would be perfectly good solution and you just inform your colleague if/when he needs to debug, that he needs to add his machine name to the list.